# Getting the primary (main), secondary and tertiary function for an emolyee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get the primary (main) and secondary function for each employee :

```
with

    employeeScopeFunctions as (

        select      e.employeeId, 
                    es.FunctionId,
                    ef.Label,
                    c.CompanyName,


                    realOrder = row_number() over(
                        partition by e.employeeId
                        order by isnull(es.sortOrder, 9999)
                    )

        from        employee e 
        LEFT JOIN       employee_scope es on es.employeeId = e.employeeId
        LEFT JOIN         employee_function ef on es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
        LEFT JOIN         Company c ON es.CompanyId = c.ID
        WHERE e.EmployeeId=54

)

select      *,
            primacy = iif(realOrder = 1, 'main', 'secondary')
from        employeeScopeFunctions
```

For the EmployeeId=54 the result is like below :

```
EmployeeId FunctionId Label                                  CompanyName realOrder Primacy
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          C1          1         primary
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          C2          2         secondary
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          X5          3         secondary
54         897        Group Regional Chief Executive Officer X6          4         secondary
54         897        Group Regional Chief Executive Officer F6          5         secondary
54         39         Director                               VY          6         secondary
54         39         Director                               G7          7         secondary
```

What I want to get is regroup all the companies for a specific function and get three levels of primacy  :

```
EmployeeId FunctionId Label                                  CompanyName  Primacy
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          C1,C2,X5     primary
54         897        Group Regional Chief Executive Officer X6,F6        secondary
54         39         Director                               VY,G7        tertiary
```

Comment: What determines the 3 levels of primacy?

Comment: @Nick the realOrder column and the Label column

Comment: So how do you compute it? it needs to be something more complicated than `iif(realOrder = 1, 'main', 'secondary')`

Comment: @Nick  the logic behing sortOrder is the minimum value gets you the main function when an Employee has one primary function for one company.In this case EmployeeId=54 has the same main function for different companies. That's why I 'm stuck with the sortOrder incremented and giving me only the first row as main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you could keep your existing CTE and turn on aggregation in the main query. `ROW_NUMBER()` can be used to rank the records by increasing `realOrder`.

This should work in SQL-Server:

```
WITH employeeScopeFunctions as (
    SELECT
        e.employeeId, 
        es.FunctionId,
        ef.Label,
        c.CompanyName,
        realOrder = row_number() over(partition by e.employeeId order by isnull(es.sortOrder, 9999))
    FROM        
        employee e 
        LEFT JOIN employee_scope es ON es.employeeId = e.employeeId
        LEFT JOIN employee_function ef ON es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
        LEFT JOIN company c ON es.CompanyId = c.ID
    WHERE e.EmployeeId=54
)
SELECT
    employeeId, 
    FunctionId,
    Label,
    CompanyName = STRING_AGG(CompanyName, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY realOrder),
    Primacy = CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(realOrder))
        WHEN 1 THEN 'primary'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'secondary'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'tertiary'
    END 
FROM employeeScopeFunctions
GROUP BY
    employeeId, 
    FunctionId,
    Label
```

Alternative solution with an additional level of nesting to avoid nesting window function and aggregation:

```
WITH employeeScopeFunctions as (
    SELECT
        e.employeeId, 
        es.FunctionId,
        ef.Label,
        c.CompanyName,
        realOrder = row_number() over(partition by e.employeeId order by isnull(es.sortOrder, 9999))
    FROM        
        employee e 
        LEFT JOIN employee_scope es ON es.employeeId = e.employeeId
        LEFT JOIN employee_function ef ON es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
        LEFT JOIN company c ON es.CompanyId = c.ID
    WHERE e.EmployeeId=54
)
SELECT
    employeeId, 
    FunctionId,
    Label,
    CompanyName,
    Primacy = CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY minRealOrder)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'primary'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'secondary'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'tertiary'
    END 
FROM (
    SELECT
        employeeId, 
        FunctionId,
        Label,
        CompanyName = STRING_AGG(CompanyName, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY realOrder),
        minRealOrder = MIN(realOrder)
    FROM employeeScopeFunctions
    GROUP BY
        employeeId, 
        FunctionId,
        Label
) x
```